# How to highlight a control when selected?

Tags: c#, .net, highlight

How can I highlight an image when it is clicked and remove the highlight when the mouse is up?

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. Capture [Control.MouseDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx)

   - Get the current color in OldColor
   - Set the new color; and it would reflect the colored control.
   - Something like `button1.BackColor = Color.Red;`
2. Capture the [Control.MouseUp Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx)

   - Set the OldColor

Answer (score 1):

Look at this  [highlight color on button click](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1926315) i think it deals with your problem

Comment: Actually what I want is when image is clicked highlight it and not to change is background color.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go for CSS psuedo classes(:active,:hover), please take a look at this code.

```
        <div class="rollover">    
           <a href="#"><img src="Jpeg/image.gif" /></a>
        </div>
        <style type="text/css">
         <!--
            .rollover a { display:block; width:32px; background-color: #FFFFFF}
            .rollover a:hover { background-color: #990000}
            .rollover a:active { background-color: #876787}
          -->
        </style>
```

Comment: Are you certain it's ASP.Net ? He hasn't tagged it like that.